# Guzzle can't work with windows-1250 (loses Polish letters)?

Tags: php, character-encoding, guzzle

I use guzzle ("guzzlehttp / guzzle": "^ 7.2") to download the rp.pl home page (Polish) with a simple request.

```
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://rp.pl');
$body = $r->getBody();
$bodyContent = $body->getContents();
file_put_contents('body.htm', $bodyContent);
```

The encoding is not specified in the header, but is specified in the body of the Windows-1250 page.
The problem is that Polish letters are lost.

**Original title on the site:**

Rp.pl: Najważniejsze wiadomości gospodarcze, prawne i polityczne z Polski i ze świata. Aktualne wiadomości z dnia - rp.pl

**The title I get is:**

Rp.pl: Najwa¿niejsze wiadomoœci gospodarcze, prawne i polityczne z Polski i ze œwiata. Aktualne wiadomoœci z dnia - rp.pl

Comment: have you tried to check it in $r before using file_get_contents that you are getting the exact letters or not

Comment: I can't check $r becouse is \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response

Comment: Try saving in UTF-8 `file_put_contents('body.htm', iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $bodyContent));` or `file_put_contents('body.htm', mb_convert_encoding($bodyContent, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1250'));`, see discussion under https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php.